# I want to use REPL in nodejs

Tags: node.js, heroku, read-eval-print-loop

I'm following tutorial that heroku provide.
At the chapter, 'start a console', I want to launch REPL by using

```
$ heroku run node
```

and I expected `>` sign,
but there is `^[[1G> ^[[0K^[[3G`

what is that sign?
and what should I do to get `>` sign that I expected?

Comment: It looks like it is trying to colour your prompt, do you have colours enabled in your shell?

Comment: No. There's no colorized :-)

Comment: type some command and I conclude It's same to '>' sign. but I don't know why cmd show '^[[1G> ^[[0K^[[3G' sign instead of '>' sign.